# Django REST Framework file upload causing an "Unsupported media type 'multipart/form-data'" error

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am newbie in Django and Django REST Framework. I have the following serializer class which I am using to upload a file along other information. But, while I run the API endpoint with uploaded file, the result is something like this:

```
HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type
Allow: POST, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "detail": "Unsupported media type \"multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryybZ07gjZAqvcsZw3\" in request."
}
```

I tried hard by googling to solve this issue, but cannot come out in a solution, so here is my serializer and API views.

Serializer:

```
class ExampleSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    example_id = serializers.IntegerField()
    description = serializers.CharField(allow_blank=True)
    example_file = serializers.FileField(allow_empty_file=True)

    def create_requirement_line(self):
        request = self.context['request']

        requirement_line = ExampleService().example_method(
            example_id=self.validated_data['example_id'],
            description=self.validated_data['description'],
            example_file=self.validated_data['example_file']
    )
    return requirement_line
```

View:

```
 class RequirementLineAPIView(BaseCreateAPIView):

    serializer_class = ExampleSerializer
    parser_classes = (FormParser,)

    def post(self, request, format=None,*args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            try:
                example_variable = serializer.example_method()
                return Response(example_variable, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

            except ValidationError as e:
                return Response(e.message, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: What is that comma all about in the line `parser_classes = (FormParser,)` ?

Comment: i am not sure,but if i remove the 'comma',then `'type' object is not iterable` is   ocurring. @kpie

Comment: Can you post more of your code?

Comment: can you please be specific?,because thats it about my serializer class and api view. @kpie

Comment: well your class has 2 variables neither of which are referenced in the provided code. It just makes me a little curious...

Comment: Also the code that actually sets the ting in motion could be good to look at.

Comment: The comma in the line `parser_classes = (FormParser,)` makes it an iterable variable, in this case a [Python tuple](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#tuple). And it seems that DRF needs it in that way. Without the comma, the `parser_classes` variable would receive a `type` value: the `FormParser` class. That would be an equivalent expression to `parser_classes = FormParser`.

To see it in a simpler way, please try these commands in a Python shell:

    x = 5
    type(x)
    x = (5)
    type(x)
    x = (5,)
    type(x)
    x = 5,
    type(x)

What do you get?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use the [MultiPartParser](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#multipartparser) instead of the FormParser if you're sending multipart/form-data.

Comment: thanks for your answer, if i use  `MultiPartParser` then i am getting the following error `UnicodeDecodeError at /api/requirement-header-line/
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 76: ordinal not in range(128)` in mention , i have applied a customize service method,is there something that i have to do in my service method?

Comment: Can you provide some more information? Like the data you're trying to send?

Comment: ok,to be specific,i am sending an integer(say 30) as my `example_id`, and 'This is a description' as a `description` and a .pptx or a .pdf file as a `example_file`. @Ivan Genchev

Comment: That should fix it: REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...
    'UNICODE_JSON': False
}

Comment: but it's not related to your original issue and also that issue depends on the settings, version of python and version of drf, that you're using...

Comment: ok,after setting that REST_FRAMEWORK = { ... 'UNICODE_JSON': False },now i am gettting the following error, `'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 14: invalid start byte`, in mention i am using python2.7 and DRF3.x and django 1.9

Comment: Thanks,your shared link really helped to understand whats the problem,technically your answer is right and i am accepting it.

Answer (score 3):

Raised if there are no parsers that can handle the content type of the request data when accessing request.DATA or request.FILES.

[check Django REST Framework2 documentation](http://www.tomchristie.com/rest-framework-2-docs/api-guide/exceptions#unsupportedmediatype)

import suitable parser

```
from rest_framework.parsers import MultiPartParser, FormParser, JSONParser

class SampleView(APIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,FormParser,JSONParser)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Using FileField parser 
[Using Parsers in django rest](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/)