# Test Upload Excel File and JSONField Django REST

Tags: python, django, excel

My `models.py` 
has 3 fields. One of them is `JSONField()`

```
attribute = JSONField(null=True, blank=True)  # Free to add any note to here
type = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=FileType.choices, default=FileType.zipcode)
file = models.FileField(upload_to='import_files')
```

I normally set `JSONField(null=True, blank=True)` for the sake of easiness.

```
def test_upload_and_process_data_complete_case(self):
    from soken_web.apps.imported_files.models import ImportFile
    with open(str(settings.BASE_DIR) + '/apps/zipcodes/complete.xlsx', 'rb') as uploaded_file:
        data = {
            'attribute': {'author': 'Singh'},
            'type': ImportFile.FileType.zipcode,
            'file': uploaded_file
        }
        response = self.client.post(reverse('api:import_file-list'), data, format='multipart')
        response.render()

        self.assertEqual(status.HTTP_201_CREATED, response.status_code)
```

And my test runs fine without shooting with `JSONField`

**Experiment:**
When I shoot with `JSONField` like the given. It will failed with this error

```
AssertionError: Test data contained a dictionary value for key 'attribute', but multipart uploads do not support nested data. You may want to consider using format='json' in this test case.
```

However, from my understanding I have to post with `multipart` because of `file`.

**Question:**
Is it possible to do unittest shoot the endpoint that has `JSONField` and `FileField` in the same time?

**Reference:**
[UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb9 in position 14: invalid start byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46490563/unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xb9-in-position-14-invalid)

Comment: can you just decode the file to a string and then send the object as format=json? What's in the file?

Comment: is right parser being used ass discused here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36881771/django-rest-framework-file-upload-causing-an-unsupported-media-type-multipart ?

Comment: @SamRedway I have never do that. Thanks for your response. This supposed to be ancient question, but I could not find the solution.

Comment: @andi Let me take time read and digest it for a big moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After played around with parser.
I found that nothing in the configurations are wrong. Only one thing I missed is. I have to put single quote cover the `{"author": "Singh"}`.
 Because web browser does submit in the `str` not python object.

```
def test_upload_and_process_data_complete_case(self):
    from soken_web.apps.imported_files.models import ImportFile
    with open(str(settings.BASE_DIR) + '/apps/zipcodes/complete.xlsx', 'rb') as uploaded_file:
        data = {
            'attribute': '{"author": "Singh"}',
            'type': ImportFile.FileType.zipcode,
            'file': uploaded_file
        }
        response = self.client.post(reverse('api:import_file-list'), data, format='multipart')
        response.render()

        self.assertEqual(status.HTTP_201_CREATED, response.status_code)
```

Comment: Also worth noting that you'll explicitly need single quotes around it (`'{"verbosity": "default"}'` will work, and `"{'verbosity': 'default', }"` will not (will throw something like it wants valid JSON, and single quotes are not allowed in JSON).